# Laravel Upload File with directory path

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

I have a form that uploads a file to the storage directory.

```
                <?php
                echo Form::open(array('url' => '/uploadFile','files'=>'true'));
                echo Form::file('file');
                echo Form::submit('Upload File');
                echo Form::close();
            ?>
```

that all works fine.  I need to add a directory to the storage path that will be dynamic. I know what the directory is on load of this form, and need to pass it along with the file itself.  How can i acheive this?

In laymens terms:

```
            <?php
                echo Form::open(array('url' => '/uploadFile','files'=>'true'));
                echo Form::file('file');
                echo Form::hiddenValue({{$someDir}});
                echo Form::submit('Upload File');
                echo Form::close();
            ?>
```

and in controller:

```
public static function uploadFile(Request $request){
    $file = $request->file('file');
    $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $path = $data['hiddenValue']."/".$fileName;
    $a = Storage::disk('public')->put($path, file_get_contents($file));
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what version of Laravel you're using, or which package you're using, since Laravel hasn't had native `Form::` in awhile, so I can't look at the docs. But I would think `hiddenValue` would need a name attribute passed somewhere, and wouldn't be called `hiddenValue`

Comment: Im only using Form:: because thats the first google result I found.  Is there a better way to upload files? what should i google?  Im using laravel 10

Comment: Just use regular [form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) and [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) tags. A hidden input would have a type of `hidden`

Answer (score 0):

Assume this is your form

```
<?php
    echo Form::open(['url' => '/uploadFile', 'files' => true]);
    echo Form::file('file');
    echo Form::hidden('directory', $someDir); // pass your value here
    echo Form::submit('Upload File');
    echo Form::close();
?>
```

**In controller**

```
public function uploadFile(Request $request){
    $file = $request->file('file');
    $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();

    $directory = $request->input('directory');

    $path = $directory . "/" . $fileName;
    $a = Storage::disk('public')->put($path, file_get_contents($file));

    return true; # add proper return
}
```

> Make sure all data is present and proper validation